# What is the | operator for std::string | std::views::transform(...)?

Tags: c++, c++20

The cppreference page for [transform_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) has the following code example:

```
    auto show = [](const unsigned char x) { std::putchar(x); };
 
    std::string in{ "cppreference.com\n" };
    std::ranges::for_each(in, show);
    std::ranges::for_each(in | std::views::transform(rot13), show);
```

The last line confuses me. What does `in | std::views::transform(rot13)` mean? Neither the page for transform_view nor the [basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) page define an `operator|`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#Range_adaptor_closure_objects

Comment: [How is overloaded operator| implemented specifically c++ range adaptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67706500/995714)